# Glusterfs for docker swarm

Tags: docker, containers, centos7, persistent-storage, glusterfs

I have glusterFS deployed on centos 7 as docker container. How to use the same for  docker swarm as persistent storage?

> ```
>    [root@localhost ~]# docker exec -ti 2c2c2e9609f0 bash
>    [root@localhost /]# gluster --version
>    glusterfs 4.1.5
>    Repository revision: git://git.gluster.org/glusterfs.git
>    Copyright (c) 2006-2016 Red Hat, Inc. <https://www.gluster.org/>
>    GlusterFS comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
>    It is licensed to you under your choice of the GNU Lesser
>    General Public License, version 3 or any later version (LGPLv3
>    or later), or the GNU General Public License, version 2 (GPLv2),
>    in all cases as published by the Free Software Foundation.
>    [root@localhost /]# gluster status
>    unrecognized word: status (position 0)
>    [root@localhost /]#
> ```